# Sending value from onpostexecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to perform Background task, After completing my task, I want to set the resultant string from onPostExecute method to another activity's constructor and from there I want to set that string to TextView. when I print log inside the constructor it's printing the string, but when i set the same string on textview, it gives empty string.(the string set on textview is empty, so it simply prints nothing.)

My AsyncTask Code :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   super.onPostExecute(s);
   Log.d("Answer1",s);
   new Answer(s);
}
```

My Answer Activity, in which I am setting the string via constructor and setting value of this string on textview, but this string is empty.

```
public class Answer extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    String str;

    //  Dont Delete this
    Answer(){

    }

    // Here, Log will print right string, but not on textview
    Answer(String str){
        this.str = str;
        Log.d("Answer2",this.str);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.SetSteps);

        // The String set here is empty, can you please elaborate???
        textView.setText(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not how Android works at all. The Android framework will never call your constructor that takes parameters, and you should never create a `new` activity yourself. To pass parameters to an activity, use extras on the intent passed to `startActivity`.

Comment: it print the string it got from onpostexecute method, but i cant access it in oncreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** instantiate an Activity youself. The correct way is to pass the desired data througn an intent to the new activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   super.onPostExecute(s);
   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, Answer.class);
   intent.putExtra("MY_DATA", s);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in your Answer activity you can receive the value:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.SetSteps);
        String result = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_DATA","");

        textView.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: i have a question, if i send Intent from OnPostExecute, won't android run only on 1 thread? then why i need to use AsyncTask, I need to run UI from main thread and set data through AsyncTask. is it possible? I mean to say is that i need to send intent through main UI thread and Data through AsynTask.

Comment: OnPostExecute gets called when you work is done, you need the async task because of the doInBackground method that will do your work in a background thread. The code in PostExecute is executed in the mainThread again exactly because you need to have access to what has been generated by the async task.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Add a Context variable to your AsyncTask

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

2 - in onPostExecute, create a new intent, add your string to the intent and start the activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Answer.class);
intent.putExtra("Answer1",s);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

3- in your Answer activity, you can get the string from the intent like below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String answer = intent.getStringExtra("Answer1");
if(answer !=null){
// do what you want
}
```

**PS:** Please please, remove constructors from your Activity, it is not recommended